# query on years old

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, date-arithmetic

i would resolve this query

> Display id, dates and time of all "LASER" interventions involving only
> doctors Having less than 30 years.

but i have an error:

> select i.id, i.data_e_ora
>
> from persona p join medico m
>
> on p.cf=m.cf
>
> join effettua e
>
> on m.cf=e.cf_med
>
> join intervento i
>
> on e.id_int=i.id
>
> where i.tipo='LASER' and p.data_nascita=((sysdate-p.data_nascita)/365)<30

```
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
```

table:

```
 CF                                        NOT NULL CHAR(16)
 NOME                                               VARCHAR2(30)
 COGNOME                                            VARCHAR2(30)
 DATA_NASCITA                                       DATE
 SESSO                                              CHAR(1)
```

Comment: Have you read the error message? Because it tells you exactly what you want to know. The date column (p.data_nascita) is stored as a number (probably a UNIX Timestamp) and not a date

Comment: You should really edit your question to show the table schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to fix the `where` clause.  It is overly ambitious:

```
select i.id, i.data_e_ora
from persona p join
     medico m
     on p.cf = m.cf join
     effettua e
     on m.cf = e.cf_med join
     intervento i
     on e.id_int = i.id
where i.tipo = 'LASER' and
      p.data_nascita > (sysdate - 365.25 * 30);
```

Note:  A better way of subtracting years is to actually subtract years:

```
where p.data_nascita > sysdate - interval '30' year
```

Comment: @Rock Because that expression will always evaluate to 30 years ago to the second, which is what the OP asked for. And *that* is why Gordon thinks it is overly ambitious. Of course, if there are thousands of doctors and most doctors perform hundreds of laser interventions (macular degeneration treatment?) per year and the data are not OLAP'd on the database server, then, yes, it is overly ambitious.

Comment: easy syntacx exists?